# ¿Cómo evaluar si una variable puede castearse?

Tags: java, android, cast

Lo que quiero hacer es:

```
  if( esta "variable" puede castearse a "esta clase"){

     haz esto;

  }else{

  haz esto otro;

 }
```

podeis ayudarme?

Comment: Evitar tratar de realizar el casting para determinar el tipo, simplemente  usa el operador instanceof.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que necesitas lo puedes realizar mediante el operador [instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

> El operador  [instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) compara un objeto con un tipo
>   especificado. Se puede usar para probar si un objeto es una instancia
>   de una clase, una instancia de una subclase o una instancia de una
>   clase que implementa una interfaz particular.

**[instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) Compara un objeto con un tipo especificado**:

```
if (objeto instanceof ClaseA) {
   //objeto es del tipo ClaseA.
}else{
   //objeto NO es del tipo ClaseA.
}
```

Como ejemplo la siguiente clase:

```
class InstanceOfUsage
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
     ClaseA objeto1 = new ClaseA();
             ClaseB objeto2 = new ClaseB();

        System.out.println("objeto1 instanceof ClaseA: "
            + (objeto1 instanceof ClaseA));
        System.out.println("objeto2 instanceof ClaseB: "
            + (objeto2 instanceof ClaseB));

        System.out.println("objeto1 instanceof ClaseB: "
            + (objeto1 instanceof ClaseB));
        System.out.println("objeto2 instanceof ClaseA: "
            + (objeto2 instanceof ClaseA));

    }


}

    class ClaseA {}
    class ClaseB extends ClaseA {}
```

Se tendría como salida:

```
objeto1 instanceof ClaseA: true
objeto2 instanceof ClaseB: true
objeto1 instanceof ClaseB: false
objeto2 instanceof ClaseA: true
```

Esta es una [demo en linea](https://www.ideone.com/UFXMLc)

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza la siguiente propiedad para verficar si es del tipo que quieres castear

```
if (obj instanceof Clase) {
    Clase c=(Clase)obj;
}
```

Comment: vale, lo probare. Ahora mimo estoy en medio de una prueba, he probado poniendo un try/catch, y digo intenta castearlo, sino, en el catch le digo como proseguir.